# move robot in rviz and gazebo

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

i want to tell a roboter where to move to in rviz (with the 2D Nav Goal) and simulate that in gazebo. does that work? and if yes, how?

thanks in advance

ps.: sry for the noobie-question, but i really don't what to do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41695/move-robot-in-rviz-and-gazebo/) by [shane](https://answers.ros.org/users/3039/shane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setup a navigation stack for your robot, see the turorial http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup. Then use gazebo for the robot simulation and from rviz send commands to */move_base* topic (another tutorial [http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using_rviz_with_the_Navigation_Stack](http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack).

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your robot already moves in gazebo you should do the following steps to move your robot in rviz:

1. add your robot model in rviz-> add button -> robot model.
2. include the p3d plugin in your robotname.gazebo.xacro file:

<xacro:if value="$(arg ground_truth)">
    <gazebo>
      <plugin name="ground_truth" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
        <frameName>world</frameName>
        <bodyName>base_footprint</bodyName>
        <topicName>/gazebo/$(arg robot_name)/odom
100.0


</xacro:if>

3. transform ground truth pose to tf (include this in your main launch file:)
4. Now launch your project and now you should be able to select in rviz->global options -> fixed frame world.

---

Originally posted by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) with karma: 311 on 2017-12-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1